# Can I capture more than one person per game?

Tags: pit-people

In one-player, I can usually only capture the last enemy standing. Is there a way to capture the last two enemies when playing with two players? Or is one just out of luck?

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit of an unsettled topic currently. The developers have said that they didn't want both players getting the last character alive as it would create a lot of duplicates which wouldn't be as fun.

They are not 100% set on whether or not they will start having both players be able to capture the last 2 enemies or not. It's something they intend to tinker with. I believe you're both able to capture enemies with nets, but whoever captures it gets it.

you may want to just go capture a bunch of people in single and then take that team to coop. If you google basically what you are asking you can find a steam discussion about where danpaladin (one of the devs) answered back a little bit.